# Can't call the server using volley library?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i am posting data to the server and while debugging i get the following error at this line. and unable to call the server.

network calls. i am using sql server version 2014, and the url to web services is `localhost:8081/api/login/signup`.

```
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.SIGN_UP,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Snackbar.make(mainlayout, response.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Responce from server", response);
                    avi.hide();
                    if(!response.contains("User")) {
                        spEdit.putString(getString(R.string.uaccount), response);
                        spEdit.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Products.class);
                        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.uemail), Email_Address);
                        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.uphone), Phone_Number);
                        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.upass), Password);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            avi.hide();
            Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
            if(error.toString().contains("NoConnectionError")) {
                Snackbar.make(mainlayout, "Internet Not Available!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Snackbar.make(mainlayout, "Webservice not responding!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String name[] = Name.split(" ");
        String first = "", last = "";
        boolean firstb = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if (firstb) {
                first += name[i];
                firstb = false;
            } else {
                if (i == name.length - 1) {
                    last = name[i];
                } else {
                    first += " ";
                    first += name[i];
                }
            }
        }
        data.put("FirstName", first);
        data.put("LastName", last);
        data.put("LoginName", Login_Name);
        data.put("PrimaryEmail", Email_Address);
        data.put("PrimaryPasscode", Encrypted_Password);
        data.put("PhoneNumber", Phone_Number);
        data.put("MobileVerificationCode", smsCode);
        data.put("AccountType", UserType);

            return data;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, REQ_TAG);
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: market.enxo.com.marketstore, PID: 3202
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
                  at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:136)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.<init>(StringRequest.java:43)
                  at market.enxo.com.marketstore.SignUp$8.<init>(SignUp.java:361)
                  at market.enxo.com.marketstore.SignUp.signUpWS(SignUp.java:332)
                  at market.enxo.com.marketstore.SignUp$4.onClick(SignUp.java:297)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What is the value of Constants.SIGN_UP

Comment: Check if your response is not null, i guess here, your String response is null and hence it is throwing NullPointerException

Comment: i am using local server, local host. and its value is 
localhost:8081/api/login/signup

Comment: Post some more code, error is not identical with this one line.

Comment: `i am using local server, local host.` are you sure you run the server on the **same device** as a client? if you run client on the android phone, localhos points to **itself** - to Android phone

Comment: @Piyush .. now check it and tell me if i can get help.

Comment: @ManXoor response.toString() here response might be null did you check that?

Comment: let me check Piyush

Comment: the thing is it doesn't execute that line. it trigers the error on the very first line.

Comment: @ManXoor, you need to indent correctly your code, it's what makes it readable by others :)